# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am getting an error when switching to iFrame

> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'driver'

What's the solution for this error? I am not sure why...

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()


url = ''

driver.get(url)
while True:
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@src="/pages/mediator-search"]')
    driver.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="mediator-name"]')))
    
    response = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
    agents = response.xpath('//a[@class="mediator-name"]')
    for agent in agents:
        outFile =  open("data.csv",'a+',newline="",encoding='utf-8')
        writer = csv.writer(outFile)
        link = agent.xpath('.//@href').get()
        vals = [link]
        writer.writerow(vals)
        outFile.close()
    
    try:
        next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "›")]')
        if next_page:
            next_page.click()
    except:
        break
```

### Need to do the following imports as well

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: it should be driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)  not driver.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`driver.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)` - Correct Here .. :). It should be `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`

Comment: I did that too .. blindly copy paste : )

Comment: 2023. I did that too ><